# extract matched data from array

Tags: javascript, data-structures

I am not able to find a best way to do it so i am asking here.

I have an array of object

```
let x = [{name: "Apple", message: {data: {}},
         {name: "dell", message: {data: {}}, 
         {name: "samsung", message: {data: {}}
        ];
```

now i have list of name that i need to check and if it is found in the array find the first one

like

```
let y = {laptop: ["Apple", "HP" ], phone: ["samsung", "Motorolla" ]
```

What i need

```
result = {
    laptop: {
      name: "Apple",
      message: {
        data: {}
      },
      phone: {
        name: "samsung",
        message: {
          data: {}
        }
      }
    }
```

this variable can be any data structure, right now best i can do is `O(n ^2)` and this check need to be done more than 40 times a second so i want to be done in efficient way. Is there any way i can do this in best possible way.

Comment: I would approach it a different way,  O(n) for preprocessing the array and O(1) for each name lookup, which is much more efficient than O(n^2)

Comment: @Mootje thank you so would that be O(n) to reading all the array and putting in an object as { Apple: 0, dell: 1, samsung: 2} then iterating over y to find index value from the object and getting that array element ? is this what you are suggesting ?

Comment: @Mootje is this what you are suggesting 

https://jsfiddle.net/oqu3c0d2/12/

Comment: @PravinPoudel Exactly. You can post it below in an Answer. Use a Stack Snippet to make it executable.

Comment: @Barmar I just realised that my code requirement is different, i will update question

Comment: Please show what you tried. We'll help you fix it, we won't write it for you.

Comment: A similar solution should work. The only difference is the output format, which is an object with the same keys as `y` instead of an array.

Comment: @Barmar it is never the case but can get both or ignore which one is faster to compute

Comment: I already deleted that comment since the question says "find the first one".

Comment: you have mobile included into laptop, seems an error in the output format

Comment: also you don't have `mobile` in the `y`

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev sorry it's a typo, in our country we say mobile to phone so it came there, just a typo

Comment: You already asked [something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053401) earlier today. You need to provide an attempt. Variable declarations are not an attempt. Also, all the names should be proper-case or lower-case; not a mix of both.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a lookup map of laptop manufacturer (brand) to index. This will give you the corresponding phone brand.

```js
const knownDevices = {
  laptop: ["Apple", "HP"],
  phone:  ["Samsung", "Motorolla"]
};

const brandToIndex = knownDevices.laptop
  .reduce((lookup, brand, index) =>
    lookup.set(brand, index), new Map);
  
console.log('Lookup:', Object.fromEntries(brandToIndex.entries()));

const deviceList = [
  { name: "Apple"   , message: { data: {} } },
  { name: "Dell"    , message: { data: {} } }, 
  { name: "Samsung" , message: { data: {} } }
];

const allowedDevices = deviceList.reduce((result, device) => {
  if (brandToIndex.has(device.name)) {
    const copy = structuredClone(device);
    const index = brandToIndex.get(device.name);
    const phoneBrand = knownDevices.phone[index];
    copy.phone = { name: phoneBrand, message: { data: {} } }
    result.push(copy);
  }
  return result;
}, []);

console.log('Filtered:', allowedDevices);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```