# extracting element from array as per another list

Tags: javascript, data-structures

is there more efficient to getting list of object that contain same property as listed in the array

```
  let x = [{
    name: "Apple",
    message: {
      data: {}
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Alienware",
    message: {
      data: {price: 20 }
    }
  },
  {
    name: "dell",
    message: {
      data: {}
    }
  },
  {
    name: "samsung",
    message: {
      data: {}
    }
  },
  {
    name: "Alienware",
    message: {
      data: {price: 25 }
    }
  }
];

let nameToCheck = ["HP", "Apple", "Nvidia", "Lenovo", "Acer", "Asus", "Alienware"];
let dataFound = [];

let nameList = {}
x.forEach((element, index) => {
  nameList[element.name] = index
})

nameToCheck.forEach((element, index) => {
  if (nameList[element] != undefined) {
    dataFound.push(x[nameList[element]])
  }
})

console.log(dataFound)
```

The array `nameToCheck` can be any data structure.

What i am trying to do is extract the objects that matches with the list of string and that in efficient way in time.

This operation need to happen in very high frequency might be around 40 times a second and list of `nameToCheck` is bigger array most probably size of 50.

Is there more time efficient way to do this ? or more nice way of doing this ?

Comment: Which of the two data structures changes most often? Does `x` change every time or does `nameToCheck` change every time? Is one of the two constant over time? Which of the two arrays has the most items? `x`?

Comment: x is what changes every 60 times in a second and nameToCheck remains fix ( i means list of string, does not need to be array can be anything). Array x is bigger.

Comment: Then [eli chens](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77053474/5459839) answer is the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

more clear way which achieve the same thing (Set is also indexed so its fast)

```js
let x = [{
    name: "Apple",
    message: {
      data: {}
    }
  },
  {
    name: "dell",
    message: {
      data: {}
    }
  },
  {
    name: "samsung",
    message: {
      data: {}
    }
  }
];

let nameList = new Set(["HP", "Apple", "Nvidia"]);
let dataFound = x.filter(el => nameList.has(el.name))


console.log(dataFound)
```

btw. in your code you don't handle cases where you have two items of the same company

Answer (score 1):

Well, instead of storing indices, you could group them by the `name`

```js
let x = [{name: "Apple", message: {data: {}}},
         {name: "dell", message: {data: {}}}, 
         {name: "samsung", message: {data: {}}}
        ];
        
const groupedX = x.reduce((acc, item) => {
  acc[item.name] = item;
  return acc;
}, {});

let nameToCheck = ["HP", "Apple", "Nvidia"];
let dataFound = [];

nameToCheck.forEach((name) => {
  const group = groupedX[name];
  if (group) {
    dataFound.push(group)
  }
})

console.log(dataFound)
```

Also depending on how critical the loop is you could convert both `reduce` and `forEach` to simple loops which are normally faster.

---

If you have to recreate the `nameToCheck` on each iteration, then you could use an object instead of a `Set` and a filter for the fastest combo.

```js
let x = [
    {name: "Apple", message: {data: {}}},
    {name: "dell", message: {data: {}}}, 
    {name: "samsung", message: {data: {}}},
];
const nameToCheck = {"HP":true, "Apple":true, "Nvidia":true};


const dataFound = x.filter(company => nameToCheck[company.name]);

console.log(dataFound);
```

See https://jsbench.me/g7lm7yni2p/1 for comparison

(*keep in mind that result can change if you extract parts outside of the critical loop*)
(*also keep in mind that results will vary, a lot in some cases, between browsers*)

Comment: i need to make it as fast as possible because in each update there is heavy task after this so dont want to consume resource in this and since this happens around 100 times in a second so need to be fast.

Comment: @PravinPoudel do you have to recreate the `nameToCheck` each time ? or could you extract that and have it ready when this code runs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Set` to store the names to check for. Now all you need to do it just filter the data.

```js
const data = [
  { name: "Apple"   , message: { data: {} } },
  { name: "Dell"    , message: { data: {} } }, 
  { name: "Samsung" , message: { data: {} } }
];

const nameToCheck = new Set(["HP", "Apple", "Nvidia"]);

const dataFound = data.filter(({ name }) => nameToCheck.has(name));

console.log(dataFound);
```

Result:

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Apple",
    "message": {
      "data": {}
    }
  }
]
```